# Ducktyping with UFCS

Tags: d

Is it possible to use `UFCS` with duck typing? In this case foo could not duck type `TestB`'s baz function.

```
module a;

struct TestA{
    void baz(){
        import std.stdio;
        writeln("Test A");
    }
}

void foo(T)(auto ref T t){
    t.baz();
}

module b;

struct TestB{}

void baz(ref TestB b){
    import std.stdio;
    writeln("Test B");
}

import a;
import b;
void main()
{
    auto testa = TestA();
    auto testb = TestB();
    testb.baz(); // works
    foo(testa); //  works
    foo(testb); // doesn't work
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The struct `TestB` has no member function `baz`, but there is a free function `baz(ref TestB)` in module `b`. The function `foo` in module `a` does not know about this free function `baz`, so it will not call it when given `TestB`. To fix this you can import `b` in module `a`.

```
void foo(T)(auto ref T t){
    import b; //alternatively, import b : baz;
    t.baz();
}
```

Comment: But this means that `foo` has to change every time if I want to add a new type with a ufcs function. Is there a way to avoid that?

Comment: I guess I could specialize `foo` for a specific type and then import the ufcs function, but that seems very hacky.

Comment: The problem is that UFCS only works if the functions are visible from the scope you're in. If you had：
--- a.d ---
void foo(T)(auto ref T obj) { writeln("General"); }
--- b.d ---
void foo(T: string)(auto ref T obj) { writeln("Special"); }
--- main.d ---
void main()
{
    import a.d;
    foo("bar"); //this will output "General", as the specialized function is not known to main.d
}

Comment: The best solution would be to make all the `baz` free functions member functions instead. If this is not possible, then keeping all of the versions of `baz` in a single module, and importing the entire module would mean all possible `baz` functions would then be known to the function `foo`.

Answer (score 2):

How about using the power of introspection?

```d
auto executor(string member, T, Args...)(auto ref T t, Args args)
{
    import std.traits : hasMember;
    static if(hasMember!(T, member))
        mixin("return t." ~ member ~ "(args);"); // t.baz()
    else
    {
        import std.traits : moduleName;
        mixin("import " ~ moduleName!T ~ ":" ~ member ~ ";"); // free function and struct need to be in the same module
        mixin("return " ~ member ~ "(t, args);"); // baz(t)
    }
}
```

which can be used like

```
executor!"baz"(testa);
executor!"baz"(testb);
executor!"baz"(testa, my, other, function, args);
// ...
```

Edit: Updated the answer after [Gassa](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1488799/gassa)'s helpful comment.

Comment: I *think* the point was to use UFCS with a free function, and the solution to that is to keep such free functions in a module and import that wherever UFCS takes place - much like std.range is needed for treating arrays as random access ranges.